# Maven compilation issues while installing?

Tags: java, maven

I am using maven to build my projects and it is working for all my projects except one. The issues I see here is:

```
[INFO] Compiling 91 source files to /ahpsan/jobs/projects/BasicsDatamart/Build_TASK_Polaris_PLM_2017/target/classes


 The system is out of resources.
 Consult the following stack trace for details.
 java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Check.checkType(Check.java:533)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr$ResultInfo.check(Attr.java:476)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.check(Attr.java:275)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)

    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.j[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
 [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
 [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
 [ERROR] An unknown compilation problem occurred
 [INFO] 1 error
 [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

The compiler plugin I am using here is:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <extraJvmArgs>-Xms768m -Xmx1048m</extraJvmArgs> 
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Could you please let me know if I am missing here something on this?

Comment: It's impossible to say what's the issue without the details of the JDK version and the source code that causes the compiler to crash.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old question, and the OP has most likely found a fix or workaround.  However, we have a rash of new answers that are probably not going to help.  So I thought it would be good to inject some better ideas.

This problem is **most likely** due to a bug in the Java compiler.  (If you trawl the Java Bugs Database and the OpenJDK Issue tracker, you will find other examples of this kind of thing.)  The repetitive nature of the stack trace indicates that something about the specific file you were compiling has triggered an infinite recursion loop in the compiler.  That is a bug.

*It is **unlikely** that you can work around this by fiddling with the Java compiler's stack or heap size parameters.*

(An infinite recursion loop will overflow *any* stack.  And this is not an OOME.)

It is also unlikely that restarting IDEs, rebuild, refetching dependencies, etc will help.  (Though it does no harm to try.)

IMO, the correct way to approach this is to do the following:

1. Try compiling with a newer (or older) Java compiler<sup>1</sup>.  The Java compiler bug may have been fixed already.
2. Trawl though the Java Bug Database and other sources looking for other reports of `StackOverflowError` failures in the Java compiler.  Look for cases where the stacktraces are similar.  If you find a good match, see if they identify what feature of *their* input Java source code that triggered the problem.  That may offer clues for tweaking *your* source code to avoid the problem.
3. Identify and try to simplify the Java source file that is triggering the failure.  Try to narrow down to the specific feature in your code that is causing the problem.  Then see if you can figure out how to avoid the problem.
4. If you get nowhere, submit a bug report with all of the evidence.  You will need to provide all the details needed for the Java engineers to reproduce the problem.  Try to provide them with a **minimal** example ... so that they don't have to waste time narrowing it down themselves.  ('Cos hard to reproduce / hard to narrow down problems tend to get put off.)
5. If you get really desperate, you could try downloading the appropriate version of the OpenJDK source code and debugging the compiler bug yourself.

---

<sup>1 - If you are going upgrade your JDK, it would be a good idea to preserve the *current state* of your development environment and tools.  That will help you to figure out how you fixed the problem ... and protect against the possibility that the upgrade actually makes things worse!</sup>

Answer (score 0):

try giving more memory in the following way to compile plugin

`<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <meminitial>512m</meminitial>
                    <maxmem>1048m</maxmem> 
                </configuration>
            </plugin>`

Here is the link https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-with-memory-enhancements.html

Comment: Thank root. I tried the option which provided but still I am having same issue. Do we have any alternate to overcome this?

Comment: Seems like your machine is out of resources. Is there something else running on your machine which is taking these resources ? can you increase the memory in the above to <maxmem>2048m<maxmem>  and try ?

Comment: Not sure the meaning of resources unavailability. But at that time, I am trying to run only this mavin install but not any other. I am getting this every time when I try to install it

Comment: in my IDE it is working perfectly fine. When I put this on servers and install it using maven install (like command line), I am facing this issue only for this projects but not for others which are similar. The other case I tried to used compiler version of 2.1 with source and target 1.5, it installed as expected with diff branch but not with current branch which I am using here

Comment: My maven install for this project is successful with Java 6 but not with jave 8. when I try the same in my local machine with java 8, it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this in your cmd window:

```
set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -Xss1024k
```

This fixed the issue for me!

Incase, error occurs agains with space issue for 1024M, try this:

```
set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx512m -Xss1024k
```

Answer (score 0):

First check the .java file in which the error occurs. Check this file in Eclipse/IntelliJ, and see if there are some errors indicated on that particular file.

Second, right click on your project folder in eclipse, select **maven** and then choose **update project** and then try to build again

Third, hit this command from cmd
**set MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1048m -Xms256m -XX:MaxPermSize=312M"**